# How to prevent the clipboard carriage return from becoming a line feed

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a cryptographic algorithm for educational purpose, and I need to be able to copy/paste unicode characters.
The problem is that the clipboard (not only the api) modifies the Carriage Return character (hex: 0x0d, dec: 13) into a Line Feed character (hex: 0x0a, dec: 10).
How can I prevent this behaviour ?

```js
let $ = s => document.querySelector(s);

let cr = String.fromCharCode(0x0d);

$("#one").addEventListener("click", function (e)
{
 navigator.clipboard.writeText(cr);
});

$("#two").addEventListener("change", function (e)
{
 $("#out").textContent = "0x" + this.value.charCodeAt(0).toString(16).padStart(2, 0);
});
```

```html
<button id="one">copy cr to clipboard</button><br>
<textarea type="text" id="two"></textarea><br>
<div id="out"></div>
```

you can test it by clicking the button to save the carriage return into your clipboard, then pasting it into the textarea.
Then click outside the textarea to trigger the change event.
It will display the 0x0a because the clipboard has turned the cr into lf.

*PS: I had to go from guided mode to traditional because it was buggy, really annoying*

Answer (score 1):

It is not related to Clipboard:

```js
const $ = s => document.querySelector(s);
const cr = String.fromCharCode(0x0d);
const firstCharAsHex = v => "0x" + v.charCodeAt(0).toString(16).padStart(2, 0);

$("#one").addEventListener("click", async function (e) {
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(cr);
  
  const v = await navigator.clipboard.readText();
  console.log("Written: " + firstCharAsHex(v));
});


$("#two").addEventListener("paste", function (e) {
  const v = e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
  console.log("Being paste: " + firstCharAsHex(v));
});

$("#two").addEventListener("change", function (e) {
  const v = this.value
  console.log("After paste: " + firstCharAsHex(v));
});
```

```html
<button id="one">Run</button><br>
<textarea type="text" id="two"></textarea><br>
```

Textarea  normalizes `CR` to `LF`. See [specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-textarea-element):

> For historical reasons, the element's value is normalized in three different ways for three different purposes.
>
> - The [raw value](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#concept-textarea-raw-value) is the value as it was originally set. It is not normalized.
> - The [API value](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#concept-fe-api-value) is the value used in the [`value`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#dom-textarea-value) IDL attribute, [`textLength`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#dom-textarea-textlength) IDL attribute, and by the [`maxlength`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#attr-fe-maxlength) and [`minlength`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#attr-fe-minlength) content attributes. **It is normalized so that line breaks use U+000A LINE FEED (LF) characters**.
> - Finally, there is the [value](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#concept-fe-value), as used in form submission and other processing models in this specification. It is normalized so that line breaks use U+000D CARRIAGE RETURN U+000A LINE FEED (CRLF) character pairs, and in addition, if necessary given the element's [`wrap`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#attr-textarea-wrap) attribute, additional line breaks are inserted to wrap the text at the given width.

Comment: With your code I get "Written: 0x0a, Being paste: 0x0a, After paster: 0x0a" on Firefox, Windows.
So if I am not mistaken the problem is with the clipboard.

Comment: Interesting, in Firefox, Mac I get, [Error, Being paste: 0x0d, After paste: 0x0a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkLdB.png) while on Chrome, I get `Written: 0x0d, Being paste: 0x0d, After paste: 0x0a`. Both are latest versions